# what does " Part of the way " mean?

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of " ***Part of the way*** " in this quote ? :

> I'm a professor at a research institution, I've written five books, I
>   rarely work past 5 pm on a weekday. **Part of the way I'm trying to be able
>   to pull that off** is because it turns out, if you treat your attention
>   with respect, so you don't fragment it, you allow it to stay whole,
>   you preserve your concentration - when it comes time to work you can do
>   one thing after another
>
> - Quit social media | Dr. Cal Newport | TEDxTysons

Comment: The "sentence"  as transcribed has a number of grammatical errors.  It is borderline gibberish.  It remains barely coherent even after the transcription errors are corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the way simply means this is one of the methods he uses, or one of the reasons that allow him not to "work past 5". The grammar in the sentence is rather clunky; I would not take it as a standard for usage.

Comment: it's a transcript (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3E7hkPZ-HTk) that's why it's so clunky

Comment: Indeed, speech seldom abides by the conventions that are so binding to writing.